# Missing dropdown menus when viewed as a publisher(user)

Tags: routes, navigation

I've used ZeroPoint theme, developed a site and it works perfect. Recently, I got to create a new user with specific roles for that I created a "publisher profile" and assigned some roles. Whatever the roles I've assigned are working fine, but the problem is when the website is viewed as a publisher the `drop-down` menus are missing. To the point, I couldn't see the drop-down for the main-menu links as a publisher and again when as an admin I could see the drop-down links.

The drop-down links appear for anonymous users. While it is not the same for `publisher/content creator`

`.

I found some part of code in page.tpl.php that deals with main-menu

```
<?php if ($main_menu || $page['dropdown']): ?>
  <div id="navlinks" class="<?php print menupos() ?>">
  <?php if (!empty($page['dropdown'])) { ?><?php print render($page['dropdown']); ?><?php } ?>
  <?php if (empty($page['dropdown'])) { ?>
  <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
            'links' => $main_menu,
            'attributes' => array(
              'id' => 'navlist',
              'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
            ),
            'heading' => array(
              'text' => t('Main menu'),
              'level' => 'h2',
              'class' => array('element-invisible'),
            ),)); ?><?php } ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What might be the problem? I have checked all the user roles and permissions there is no kind of thing that deals with page views. Any Ideas??

Comment: it sounds like a permissions problem. do you have field or node access / content modules installed?  one way to test (takes some time though) set up a new account giving all permissions - then start taking permissions away one at a time until the menus disappear. then you will know what the culprit is

Comment: Good idea though... I've field module installed but no node access/content.

Comment: I meant field access module, sorry, but that shouldn't affect it that way anyhoo, but the process I mentioned before will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: ohhh I've no field access module, is there any way to solve it using those modules??

Comment: there's no way to solve it until you know what the problem is. There's still no guarantee it's a permissions problem - that was an assumption, and the method I mention will determine if that is in if fact true

Comment: I agree, let me try..

Comment: I tried it, created a new role assigned all the permissions same as that of admin's. But there was no change the drop-down doesn't appear. I don't know why..

Comment: I think there is no issue with permissions. The problem exists somewhere else.. what u say @Geoff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17245/discussion-between-giri-and-geoff).

Comment: won't let me log in to chat for some reason... will deal with that later - if an 'admin' doesn't have access, then something is restricting it to user 1 only, for some reason. is your menu in a block, or rendered normally? check page.tpl.php for the menu rendering and see if there's an if statement that might be causing the problem.

Comment: @Geoff I've checked the page.tpl.php page. I found something that deals with dropdown menu links. I've updated it in my question.

Comment: if you haven't already, check to make sure the following has been done as per the install instructions: To activate the drop-down menu put the Main menu block in the "Drop Down menu" region and set the correct levels to "expanded" (the parent item).  As well, since it is a block, check the display settings for the block (under configuration, at the bottom of the page) and make sure it isn't being restricted by role